# Center Loading Css in entire page

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to put a loading css right in the center of my screen and I want it to work mobile as well as in desktop. Currently, my CSS is this:

```
.spinner {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position:absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 100px auto;
  z-index:99999;
}

.double-bounce1, .double-bounce2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #333;
  opacity: 0.3;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index:99999;

  -webkit-animation: sk-bounce 2.0s infinite ease-in-out;
  animation: sk-bounce 2.0s infinite ease-in-out;
}

.double-bounce2 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -1.0s;
  animation-delay: -1.0s;
  z-index:99999;
}
```

[This is what I currently have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJyt8.png)

You can see it is not entirely centered and I don't know how to achieve this. The spinner div is in my application.html.erb inside the body tag above the yield.

How can I center this at the exact center of the web page including the sidenav and navbar?

Comment: `.spinner` position is relative to his first parent with `position: relative`. Try to put it right after `<body>`. BTW, you should post testable code, there's not enough information to do it.

Comment: As your div.spinner is position: absolute relatively to the body it is centered relatively to the body instead of the white part, so you should place it inside this white div part and make this dive.white or whatever you called it position: relative, so the spinner will then be relatively to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below CSS inside `.spinner`:

```
transform: translate(calc(-50%), calc(-50%));
position: fixed; /* if absolute doesn't work */
margin: 0; /* no need of margin */
```

Answer (score 0):

So the fix was easy... I just added the code below to the .spinner class in the CSS.

```
transform: translate(calc(-50%), calc(-50%));
position: fixed;
```

The only thing I still have a problem with is that the spinner is too far down. I think changing `top: 50%` to `top: 40%` might do the trick.

Comment: Can you provide an image of your current situation?